# Given a list of strings, how to locate position of first string matching substring using RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the body of an email parsed into a list of strings (each line is a string). Emails that are replies will have a section along the bottom that is repeating the prior email and begin with " > ", like this....

```
Hi Dude,

This is just an example.

On Fri, Apr 1, 2016 at 10:14 AM, Some Dude (somedude@example.com)

> The prior email text
```

I'd like to run some text analytics on the message using NLP, but would like to drop the junk at the bottom first. I imagine what I want to use is the **re** module, find the following line via regex:

```
On Fri, Apr 1, 2016 at 10:14 AM, Some Dude (somedude@example.com)
```

And once I have the location, slice the list to that position. But I'm having trouble locating the position of that line. There's probably sexier ways to write this, but here's what I have so far:

```
pattern = r'\AOn +([A-Z]+[a-z]{2}), +([A-Z]+[a-z]{2}) +([1-31])'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(text) if re.search(pattern, x)]
```

I presume my issue is in my regex pattern (which does appear valid and does match the line in places like https://www.regex101.com/, but I'm stuck there as indices is returning an empty set `[]`. In the example text provided above, I'd like it to return 4 (the 5th line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate(text)` is an iterator over characters of `text`. Since you want to find the line number, you'll have to iterate over lines. For example, you could split `text` into individual lines using `str.split('\n')`.

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(text.split('\n')) if x and re.search(pattern, x)]
[4]
```

Considering that you only need to find the first matching line, it's possible to use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and a generator expression like this:

```
>>> next(i for i, x in enumerate(text.split('\n')) if x and re.search(pattern, x))
4
```

---

To get the rest of the text you could concatenate the "remainder" of the iterator:

```
>>> it = enumerate(text.split('\n'))
>>> next(i for i, x in it if x and re.search(pattern, x))
4
>>> '\n'.join(x for _, x in it)
'\n> The prior email text\n'
```

or alter the regular expression to match the whole line:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'On +([A-Z]+[a-z]{2}), +([A-Z]+[a-z]{2}) +([1-31]).*?\n', text)
>>> text[match.end():] # Don't forget to check if match is None
'\n> The prior email text\n'
```

---

You'd avoid using regex, especially if all you need to find is the position of the `>` character.

```
>>> text[text.index('>'):]
'> The prior email text\n'
```

Comment: This works, but as a follow-up, how would I slice the original body text given the specific line number determined here given that text is just a single string?

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this problem different. Iterate over all the lines.

Start with `junk_begins = -1`
When you see a line starting with `>` (no need for a regex, just use [startsWith](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm)), set `junk_begins` to the current line `if junk_begins == -1`.
When you see a line starting WITHOUT `>`, set `junk_begins` back to `-1`

After looping through all the lines, you will have `junk_begins` pointing to the line number of the first line where every line afterwards starts with `>`

Comment: So, this definitely works, I just had to adjust the start of count for the empty row.

Answer (score 1):

No regex required. Before you make the list(consume the iterator, I mean) filter it,

```
cleaned = [line for line in source if not line.lstrip().startswith(">")]
```

See if it woks.